# Graphical Issue

Tags: grub2, graphics, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

Alright so I looked through [my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but it does not seem to completely fix my issue.

Here are specs of my computer that might matter and it is a custom computer:

Mobo - M5A99X
CPU - FX 8350
GPU - R9 270

I am running Ubuntu 16.10, but every time I boot to it I have to hit e and add in `nomodeset` to see anything. Once I am at the Desktop 1 of 2 things happens the resolution will be terrible 800x600 or look normal 1920x1080. With 800x600 that is the only choice I have and with 1080 I am able to choose different resolutions.

So after looking around and also in the above guide I can set nomodeset in grub, but when I do that 800x600 is always the resolution. Also tried changing GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080, but when I do that I get an error about 800x600 being my only resolution.

I just don't understand why the open source drivers don't work for me, but I have looked for people with same GPU and Ubuntu seems to work just fine with the open source drivers. If I install 14.04.4 or I guess 15.10 and install the fglrx drivers there aren't any issues, but I want security updates.

I've been trying to learn Linux better, but this is making me go crazy =(

I also had Oibaf gpu ppa installed hoping maybe newer drivers would help? Removing it now so we don't have to deal with that =D

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Well I just wiped my comp again and then forgot to put nomodeset in grub and my computer booted to desktop just fine. Might of just been an update that saved my life

Finally I have fixed my computer. Randomly found someone talking about R9 270 drivers aren't in Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 and also found out those drivers are supposed to be in kernel 4.9. I then set out to get this working.  Unfortunately no fancy code, but a PPA or 2.

I take that back I did follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) from askubuntu to get the mainline kernels installed for 4.9. A guide I found [Here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-linux-kernel-4-9-ubuntu-linux-mint/) (tried this before asking for help) didn't work for me even though it downloads them from the kernel site? Alright after I did this I ran`uname -r` shows your current kernel (which showed 4.9 and I gave myself a high five for being awesome)and `uname -a` does the same, but with more info that didn't help me.

For the next part I am pretty sure I needed the 1st PPA, but the 2nd might be needed. As of right now I am too scared to test it, because I finally got this working.

[xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is the PPA I used to update xorg. I was hoping xorg 1.19 since I read that is what I needed for kernel 4.9 to run and xserver amdgpu driver. I learned that manually doing xorg upgrade is probably a bad idea. Anyway long story short I found what I needed in here.
The other PPA was [oibaf PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) uses most up to date GPU drivers. I believe some drivers from xorg-edgers are in here and that why it may not be necessary.

Make sure to update computer afterwards.

Now I boot with not issues and in details it lists the driver Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN (DRM 2.48.0 / 4.9.0-040900-generic, LLVM 3.9.1) instead of gallium on llvmpipe (I think thats what it said). I hope this guide is useful and to now test me some games!